# Simple projection of bipartite (two-mode) graph not working in igraph 0.7.1

Tags: xml, igraph, graphml

Consider this simple, bipartite graph in GraphML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
         http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key id="type" for="node" attr.name="type" attr.type="boolean">
    <default>TRUE</default>
  </key>
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
    <node id='p1'><data key='type'>FALSE</data></node>
    <node id='o1'></node>
    <node id='o2'></node>
    <edge id='e1' source='p1' target='o1'></edge>
    <edge id='e2' source='p1' target='o2'></edge>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

Now consider this R session:

```
require("igraph")
graph <- read.graph(file="bipartitetest.graphml",format="graphml")
proj <- bipartite.projection(graph)
```

Although the graph object seems fine:

```
graph
IGRAPH D--B 3 2 -- 
+ attr: type (v/l), id (v/c), id (e/c)
```

my igraph version 0.7.1 [complains](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/commit/7ac9d47fb05d01198ed4e086ecd1edbe8e74b907):

```
Error in .Call("R_igraph_bipartite_projection", graph, types, as.integer(probe1),  : 
  At bipartite.c:198 : Non-bipartite edge found in bipartite projection, Invalid value
```

Why is that? The simple graph seems to be valid a-priori.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an igraph bug, but seemingly it ignores the default value of the `type` attribute:

```
V(graph)$type
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The workaround is to specify it explicitly, until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Related bug report that I have just created: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/684